# What Can/Cannot be done inside a Generic repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an asp.net mvc-5 with Entity framework 6. now currently i am not using any kind on generic repositories , as the ones mentioned here:-

[Link-1](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

&

[Link-2](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-the-repository-pattern-with-asp.net-mvc-and-entity-framework.htm)

now the generic repository gives you a feeling that you can do everything in a generic way.. but inside these 2 links seems what can be generilzed are the basic operations for get, add, delete & modify which are by defualt provided inside Entity framework. so can anyone adivce on thses question regading using Generic repositories with EF-6 & MVC-5:-

1.is it really a good approach of using Generic repo ? as seems generic repo will just provide what EF already provide !!

2.let say i have two Parent/Child (DataCenter/Zone) objects:-

```
public class DataCenter
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public byte[] timestamp { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<Zone> Zones { get; set; }
    }

 public class Zone
    {


        public int ZoneID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int DataCenterID { get; set; }

        public virtual DataCenter DataCenter { get; set; }

    }
```

now using the Generic repository i can Get,Add,Edit,Delete these 2 objects using the same generic repo methods. but let say i want to retrieve all the Zones related to a specific Datacenter as follow:-

```
var results = entity.DataCenters.SingleOrDefault(a => a.ID == id).Zones.Where(a => a.Name.Contains("1"));
```

so can the generic repository support such a query , in a way that i can re-use the query with another object types (other than Datacenter & zones). for example to have a generic query :- to get a parent object by ID and for its child to get the childs that have their names contain the  word "1" ?? and what if the parent have multiple child types !! will the generic repository support non-generic queries and operations ?

Comment: A) yes, because you could replace EF with ServiceStack if you wanted to; its always good to decouple when possible. B) Yes, in principle your repository implementations could do the hand-work for you and retrieve the referenced objects from other tables. ServiceStack.OrmLite can do it. https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#reference-support-poco-style

Comment: @MeirionHughes now currently i do not use ServiceStack i only use EF-6 so will EF support re-using my above query which query a parent/child objects?

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same question... I first did a specific repository, then I changed to a generic. But I've ended up having to code so much specific queries, that I decide to change for non-generic repositories, returning ToList (I didn't want IQueryable) and using Unit of Work pattern. Now I think I'm happy with the way things are.

Edit:
Query the child by it's property, bringing back the parent too (is that what you want?):

```
return await _context.Entity.Include(e => e.Parent)
                            .Where(e => e.SomeProp == someParam)
                            .ToListAsync();
```

Or, Querychild, using some property in the parent, bringing back The parent:

```
return await _context.Entity.Include(e => e.Parent)
                                .Where(e => e.Parent.SomeProp == someParam)
                                .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: so you mean you ended up having multiple specialized repositories which are managed together using Unit or work ?  this the same approach i am following.. but you did not answer my question if i can define a general query such as :- to get a parent object by ID and for its child to get the childs that have their names contain the word "1"

Comment: Just an observation: as you are using the Unit of Work approach, you could query the parent through the UnitOfWork, but I edited my answer. I hope it helps you.